# How many mapper and reducer will it take for xyz scenario?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Scenario:I have node A and node B,each having 100 mb of disk space.And I want to store 128MB file in it(let replication factor be 1 and block size be 64MB).How file will store in this scenario? Also how many mapper and reducer will be needed to process this file?
Let say I wanna process this file with one mapper,then which node will run this mapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are talking about 2 data nodes A & B, because cluster as a whole has only A & B, either of them need to be name node which cannot store any data.

File will be split into two 64MB blocks and **A & B will host one block each**. Can't say who will have the first and who will have second.

In default setup, **2 mappers** will process the splits in their respective nodes and **one reducer** will process both mappers' output.

If you want to force to use one mapper only, data node of the **first task tracker that heart beats into the job tracker** will run the mapper.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks man! I would like to know more about it,why only one reducer will run? Any specific reason?

Comment: One reducer is the default if number of reducers is not set in the driver with `JobConf.setNumReduceTasks(int)`.